# How to write nested if function in Excel for the below condition

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am having an excel sheet with columns A to H and need to write a formula satisfying the below condition which has multiple nested If conditions:

if D < C and C <= B

```
    if J <= D, Value - D
    if J > D and J <= C and G <= 2%, Value - C
    else Value - None
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this formula:

```
=IF(AND(D1<C1,C1<=B1),IF(J1<=D1,D1,IF(AND(J1<=C1,G<=2%),C1,"")),"")
```